# Time series, find how much value in one column decreases after the value in another column every day

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I have half-hourly time series with two variables **value** and **state**. An example day would look like this:

```
date                value state
2017-01-10 00:00    17    0
2017-01-10 00:30    17    0
2017-01-10 01:00    16    0
2017-01-10 01:30    16    0
2017-01-10 02:00    16    0
2017-01-10 00:00    16    0
...                 ...   ...
2017-01-10 21:00    23    1
2017-01-10 21:30    23    1
2017-01-10 22:00    20    0
2017-01-10 22:30    18    0
2017-01-10 23:00    17    0
2017-01-10 23:30    16    0
```

*And this goes for many days.*

I need to find how much the **value** decreases in the space of 3 hours after the last **state**=1 of the day, for each day.

Thank you!

Comment: The last `state=1` is at 21:30. 3 hours later would be 00:30 on the next day which your example does not provide. Please try and edit this to provide a reproducible example with a dataframe that can be loaded by others (using `dput`) as well as your expected answer.

Comment: Thank you, still learning the ropes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data that covers multiple days:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(timestamp = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-01-10 00:00:00"), length.out = 48*4, by = "30 mins"))
dat$value <- sample(15:30, size = nrow(dat), replace = TRUE)
dat$state <- rbinom(nrow(dat), 1, 0.1)
head(dat)
#             timestamp value state
# 1 2017-01-10 00:00:00    15     0
# 2 2017-01-10 00:30:00    19     0
# 3 2017-01-10 01:00:00    15     0
# 4 2017-01-10 01:30:00    23     0
# 5 2017-01-10 02:00:00    24     0
# 6 2017-01-10 02:30:00    18     0
```

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(state == 1)) %>%
  filter(first(state) == 1, timestamp <= (first(timestamp) + 3600*3)) %>%
  summarize(
    timestamp_1 = first(timestamp), timestamp_n = last(timestamp),
    value_1 = first(value), value_n = last(value),
    value_max = max(value), value_min = min(value),
    dip = max(first(value) - value)
  ) %>%
  group_by(date = substring(timestamp_1, 1, 10)) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 9
#     grp timestamp_1         timestamp_n         value_1 value_n value_max value_min   dip date      
#   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>                <int>   <int>     <int>     <int> <int> <chr>     
# 1     3 2017-01-10 21:00:00 2017-01-11 00:00:00      20      16        24        16     4 2017-01-10
# 2     7 2017-01-11 21:30:00 2017-01-12 00:30:00      30      26        30        19    11 2017-01-11
# 3    14 2017-01-12 21:00:00 2017-01-13 00:00:00      21      23        28        15     6 2017-01-12
# 4    20 2017-01-13 19:30:00 2017-01-13 22:30:00      29      24        29        16    13 2017-01-13
```

I wasn't certain if you meant "value[time+3h] - value[1]" or if you meant the max of "value - value[1]" for each group; the current `dip` is the max dip, not necessarily `value - value[1]`. To cover and demonstrate this, I've included the first/last timestamp (for proof of 3h window) and first/last/min/max value for each group.

It calculates these stats for all groups during each day, not just the last group of the day; if we group by day first before summarizing, we will lose those cases where the 3h window goes over midnight.